# Page unresponsive when using test console in publisher/dev portal

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

When I was testing the API in integrated test console of publisher/dev portal, I got page unresponsive error as shown in the attached picture, waited 20 mins but didn't get any results. The result data is very large size.
How can I load large size html/text in test console?

API Manager Version: 4.0.0

[Page unresponsive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FpQ6.png)

**Response: Header**

**HTTP/1.1** 200 OK

**Connection**: close

**Content-Type**: text/html; charset=utf-8

**Content-Length**: 2411185

Answer (score 0):

APIM uses the swagger-ui library for the tryout consoles. It seems this is a known issue[1] in the swagger-ui.

You will have to use an external tool (like Postman) as a workaround.

[1] - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3832